# I have started getting the following error recently on release change action in AWS codePipeline console. Also attaching the screenshot

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

```
Invalid action configuration
The input artifact, codepipeline-ap-south-1-359590581532/deliv_Module/BuildArtif/saPzkcn, does not exist or you do not have permissions to access it: The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; Request ID: A2WSY5359TJMCZ4V; S3 Extended Request ID: cnf3XMLT+B+p90oJZHDuJfM5nsCyD1JLVFjgqqaGATx2KRuHmxM//tXJIz0FnSJQPFZfMAVDt0o=; Proxy: null)
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason BuildArtif is not being created in specific bucket. It has to store in bucket so that during deployment it can be access from there. But that artifact file missing it causing this error. I am having same issue. But I don't know why that `BuildArtif` is missing. I have only 3 phases. `Source, Build and Deploy`. `SourceArtif` I can see it in bucket but not `BuildArtif`

Answer (score 0):

You can check The Role/permissions of the CodePipeline if he have access to the bucket S3 which contains the artifact, and also have permissions of KMS.... , Also if the bucket and the Codepipeline are in the same region.

And check also if the artifact exist on the bucket S3.